# OpenGL indicesBuffer are they worth using?

Tags: opengl, shader

I am currently learning OpenGL for 3D rendering and i can't quite wrap my head around some things regarding shaders and VBOs, i get that all VBOs share one index and therefore you need to duplicate some data

but when you create more VBOs there are nearly no faces with vertices that share the same position normal and texture coordinates so the indices are at least from my point of view pretty useless, it is basically just an array of consecutive numbers.

Is there an aspect of indicesBuffers i don't see ?

Comment: What, are you rendering a bunch of cubes? Have you considered how non-cube meshes, or smooth meshes, might work?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am rendering low polygon models

Comment: And my point is that non-faceted, high-polygon models obviously have a lot more sharing of vertices than what you're rendering. Just because a tool isn't useful for your use case shouldn't mean that you should consider it wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The utility of index buffers is, as with the utility of all vertex specification features, dependent on your mesh data.

Most of the meshes that get used in high-performance graphics, particularly those with significant polygon density, are smooth. Normals across such meshes are primarily smooth, since the modeller is usually approximating a primarily curved surface. Oh yes, there can be some sharp edges here and there, but for the most part, each position in such models has a single normal.

Texture coordinates usually vary smoothly across meshes too. There are certainly texture coordinate edges; well-optimized UV unwrapping often produces these kinds of things. But if you have a mesh of real size (10K+ vertices), most positions have a single texture coordinate. And tangents/bitangents are based on the changes in texture coordinates, so those will match the texture topology.

Are there meshes where the normal topology is highly disjoint with position topology? Yes. Cubes being the obvious example. But there are oftentimes needs for highly faceted geometry, either to achieve a specific look or for low-polygon uses. In these cases, normal indexed rendering may not be of benefit to you.

But that does not change the fact that these cases are the *exception*, generally speaking, rather than the rule. Even if your code always involves these cases, that simply isn't true for the majority of high-performance graphics applications out there.

Answer (score 2):

In a closed mesh, every vertex is shared by *at least* two faces. (The only time a vertex will be used fewer than three times is in a double-sided mesh, where two faces have the same vertices but opposite normals and winding order.) Not using indices, and just duplicating vertices, is not only inefficient, but, at minimum, doubles the amount of vertex data required.

There’s also potential for cache thrashing that could be otherwise avoided, related pipeline stalls and other insanity.

Indices are your friend. Get to know them.

**Update**

Typically, normals, etc. are stored in a normal map, or interpolated between vertices.

If you just want a faceted or "flat shaded" render, use the cross product of `dFdx()` and `dFdy()` (or, in HLSL, `ddx()` and `ddy()`)to generate the per-pixel normal in your fragment shader. Duplicating data is bad, and only necessary under very special and unusual circumstances. Nothing you've mentioned leads me to believe that this is necessary for your use case.

Comment: If you have normal + vertex+ tangent  you have almost no repeating vertices

Comment: @EvgenyKaravashkin: Across what kind of mesh? Most meshes are not faceted, so the normals would be smooth. And most meshes use smooth texture coordinates, so the tangents/bitangents would be smooth. So what kinds of meshes are you talking about.